# Default Charset on Heroku (US-ASCII) causing problems

Tags: java, heroku, utf-8, character-encoding, base64

We have a maven--jetty-based Java app deployed on heroku.

Locally, when I do:

```
System.out.println("Default Charset = "+ Charset.defaultCharset());
String s = "Resumé of Schrödinger";
System.out.println("s = "+ s);`
```

I see (*as expected*):

```
Default Charset = UTF-8
s = Resumé of Schrödinger
```

But, when I push the app to heroku, and check the logs, I see:

```
Default Charset = US-ASCII
s = Resum?? of Schr??dinger
```

Actually, I'm facing further problems because of this, since we have to Decode Base-64 encoded text which has UTF-8 encoded characters.

I have even tried the following with no use:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
InputStream iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlAsString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(iStream, "UTF-8");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

And later, when doing `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(byte [])` I am even doing `stringObject.getBytes("UTF-8")`

But still, I am unable to see the characters like e-acute(é), umlaut(ö), etc.

Is there any way to solve this on Heroku?

The jdk version in pom.xml is 1.6

Is it a quirk of the OpenJDK 1.7 & the virtual machine underneath in Heroku?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this sounds terrible. I know the ruby buildpack sets `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and that ensures ruby apps default to unicode. Not sure about the java buildpack, tho. What are the contents of your `heroku config`? Be sure to remove any sensitive information like connection credentials.

Comment: Looks like openjdk is the culprit

Comment: My heroku config values are as below:

     JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
     MAVEN_HOME: .
     MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
     PATH: /app/.jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I got in touch with the friendly staff at Heroku--they gave the following suggestion to over-ride `file.encoding` property via the `JAVA_OPTS` env-variable.

Issued the following from my Heroku Toolbelt, & things began working now.

```
heroku config:add JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

This way, the JVM picks it up, & now `Charset.defaultCharset( )` returns `UTF-8`, with special characters appearing as they should!

They also said, we could alternatively do the following as well:

```
heroku config:add JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

Also, it would be a good idea to embed this property right into the [**Procfile**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) of the app, so that our code behaves the same when we push it to a new Heroku app.

Answer (score 2):

Set `file.encoding` system variable. Open jdk uses this to get the default characterset.

Comment: Yeah, I even tried specifying `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to java, but to no avail. :-(

Comment: And now, even tried setting this property in the `system.properties` file in the root-level of my app. Still the value of `Charset.defaultCharset()` is `US-ASCII`

Comment: did u enable the lab feature....when build pack installs jvm, it may not be able to access this variable unless the lab feature to access  system variables

Comment: Yes, enabled the labs feature of `user-env-compile`, but no effect. I believe this makes the ENV variables 'available' to the compiler...