# Can't change encoding with my procfile

Tags: java, maven, heroku

[image]
I'm having problems with charsets while generating some documents because of Charset.
I'm setting my environment to -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 and it get overrided by heroku settings or it might even gets read.

As reply for being duplicated, that's a different question 
[image]

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Charset on Heroku (US-ASCII) causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106076/default-charset-on-heroku-us-ascii-causing-problems)

Comment: @Rcordoval nope, using Spark http://sparkjava.com

Comment: Can you show us your procfile please?

Comment: @Rcordoval the procfile is inline, you may check it in the first image 'Starting process with command `java -D..........